# How can I use bootstrap popover in ag grid cell in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag grid where I am customizing few columns and using bootstrap popover attributes with below method -

```
private createColumnDefs() {
   this.columnDefs = [{headerName: 'Description', field: "description", headerTooltip: "Description",minWidth: 150,
                    cellRenderer: function(params){
                    var text = params.data.description;
                    return '<a title="Description" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-content="'+text+'">'+text+'</a>';
                }}
        ];
    }
```

Now I am initializing popover using jQuery as below -

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

But it seems that the jquery code is getting executed before `Description` column in the grid is rendered. The popover doesn't work. Could anyone suggest a solution or approach I should use here.

Comment: Have you tried using the `onGridReady` event?

Comment: @mrtig : yes indeed, i had the same issue, and it's often because your compoenents are not yet drawn, so you call popover() on nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above in comments you have to make sure that grid is ready and all html elements have been rendered before calling popover method on them.

also you need to make sure that **bootstrap**,**Jquery** and **popper** are already loaded in the memory so that your code can make use of them. I added them additionally in  index.html file.

```
    onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api; // your usual operations  
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi; // your usual operations
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
    }
```

check out this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gJr6IKiibpQIdvar).